# What is the filter to search for EC2 instances with NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I'm trying to search for ec2 instances with NVIDIA gpus.

I've tried the following

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types \
    --region eu-west-3 \
    --filters "Name=gpu-info.gpus.manufacturer,Values=NVIDIA"
```

However, I get the error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeInstanceTypes operation: The filter 'gpu-info.gpus.manufacturer' is invalid

If I describe all instances:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types --region eu-west-3
```

I see the following:

```
           ...
           "GpuInfo": {
            "Gpus": [
                {
                    "Name": "T4",
                    "Manufacturer": "NVIDIA",
                    "Count": 4,
                    "MemoryInfo": {
                        "SizeInMiB": 16384
                    }
                }
            ],
            "TotalGpuMemoryInMiB": 65536
        },
        ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `filter` defined for that field, but you can use [JMESPATH](https://jmespath.org/examples.html) to specify the desired records:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types --query 'InstanceTypes[?GpuInfo!=null].[InstanceType]' --output text --region eu-west-2
```

This is a bit of a cheat because it is merely checking whether the `GpuInfo` exists. At the moment, the only GPU type used on Amazon EC2 is `NVIDIA`. I couldn't quite figure out how to check the value of the manufacturer in the expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-types --query 'InstanceTypes[?GpuInfo.Gpus!=null].[InstanceType, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Count,  GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Manufacturer, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].MemoryInfo.SizeInMiB, GpuInfo.Gpus[0].Name]' --output text
```

would output:

```
g3.16xlarge     4       NVIDIA  8192    M60
g4dn.metal      8       NVIDIA  16384   T4
g4ad.8xlarge    2       AMD     8192    Radeon Pro V520
g4ad.4xlarge    1       AMD     8192    Radeon Pro V520
p3.2xlarge      1       NVIDIA  16384   V100
...
```